# ASP.NET IDENTITIES Turn On when i publish

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-4

When i publish my MVC4 C# website on my server, the IIS authentication "Take Identity of ASP.Net" is turning On automatically.

How can i do for let this authentication "Off" ?

Answer (score 1):

It's working with that code in WebConfig :

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="false" />
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```